# Can sendmail use mailutils to forward incoming mail?

Tags: sendmail

I am using sendmail and mailutils.

I am able to send outgoing mail using mailutils.

I am able to receive incoming mail to my domain using sendmail.

However when I try to forward emails using the /etc/mail/aliases to an outside email address that doesn't work.

I am also not able to send outgoing mail using sendmail. It does not give any error but email never gets sent. It gets queued and never gets sent. My mail log reads as follows:

```
Nov 10 22:27:38 localhost sendmail[159282]: 0AAMRbLo159282: from=root@localhost, size=2141, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202011102227.0AAMRbLo159282@my.domain.com>, relay=root@localhost
Nov 10 22:27:38 localhost sm-mta[159286]: 0AAMRckL159286: from=<root@my.domain.com>, size=2364, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202011102227.0AAMRbLo159282@my.domain.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Nov 10 22:27:38 localhost sendmail[159282]: 0AAMRbLo159282: to=myname@gmail.com, ctladdr=root@localhost (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=32141, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (0AAMRckL159286 Message accepted for delivery)
Nov 10 22:27:38 localhost sm-mta[159288]: STARTTLS=client, relay=aspmx.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.3, verify=FAIL, cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits=256/256
Nov 10 22:27:38 localhost sm-mta[159288]: 0AAMRckL159286: to=<myname@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<root@my.domain.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=122364, relay=aspmx.l.google.com. [74.125.71.26], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK  1605047258 r7si170039wrs.226 - gsmtp)
```

It says `verify=FAIL` in the STARTTLS line.
What do I have to change in order to get my sendmail to forward emails?

Comment: The last log entry you included indicated successful email transfer. Which Linux distribution do you use? [Hints for installing Certification Authority certificated may depend on it[

Comment: @AnFi Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Started working this morning!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @AnFi this works.

Sendmail is a complete solution for receiving & sending emails. It is fairly easy to setup. You don't need Postfix.